# Why is probability a measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ is a random variable then it seems that a statement like the following makes sense, $P[ \vert X - a \vert > b ] = \int_{\vert X - a\vert > b} dP$

Can someone explain why does $``dP"$  make sense as an integration measure where $P$ is a probability ?

Comment: What else than a measure is a "probability" for you? If you give your definition of $P$, one can try to help you ...

Comment: Two of the three axioms of probability (non-negativity, $P(\Omega)=1$ and countable additivity of probabilities of disjoint events) are explicitly similar to typical requirements in the definition of a measure (non-negativity and countable additivity of measures of disjoint sets). The other simply restricts the type of measure to a *probability measure*

Answer (score 1):

By definition of Lebesgue integrals for simple functions,
$$
\int _A\mathrm d\mu = \int 1_A\mathrm d\mu = \mu(A).
$$
In your case $\mu = P$. Probability measure is a measure, right?

Comment: For the LHS to make sense isn't $P$ a real valued map on  a Borel algebra of sets in the sample space which is $X$'s domain?

Comment: @user6818 For LHS to make sense, $\{\omega: |X(\omega) - a| > b\}$ must be in the domain of $P$. This holds e.g. when $P$ is defined on the whole $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$.

Comment: I guess the way to make sense of the RHS is to say that $\int dP$ is $\int 1 dP$ and now since $1$ is a bounded measurable function one can write it as as the limit of a sums of ``simple" functions which can be chosen as indicator functions over some $n-$partition say $\{ A_i \}_{i=1}^{n}$ of the set $\vert X - a \vert > b$ and then one would have $\int_{ \vert X - a \vert > b} dP =lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$. (where implcitly we are choosing a different A-partiton for each $n$ and these choices do not matter) Right?

Comment: @user6818: yes, but this is so trivial, that it is omitted $P$-almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are two measures in play here one on the sample space and one on the range of the random variable which is also a measuable function which makes the two measures very related. Read about it in first chapter of Shiryaev's book on Probability. To understand your problem in detail you can use Chatadory extension theorem once you know that to each probalitly denisty function there is a distribition function satisfying some conditions which is needed to "create" a measure. This the last pages of chaper 1 section 3 in Cohns book on measure theory.